# malloc() triggers breakpoint in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have this program (school exercise) that simulates a software for managing tests and exercises. Everything works fine... until it doesn't. The second time, in the menu of the program, I want to add an exercise (calling so the function called *inserisciEsercizio*, "addExercise" in English), the malloc (*esercizioPtr newEsercizio = (esercizioPtr)malloc(sizeof (esercizio));*) "triggers a breakpoint". I attach the function and where the structs are declared.
What does that mean? How can I resolve it? 
Thank you.

I tried looking it up, but I couldn't find anything that could help me understand.

The variables are written in Italian (half in Italian, half in English to be honest). Hope it's not too much of a problem.

```
struct ListaEsercizi
{
    esercizioPtr esercizio;
    struct ListaEsercizi *nextListaEsercizi;
};
typedef struct ListaEsercizi listaEsercizi;
typedef listaEsercizi *listaEserciziPtr;
struct Esercizio
{
    char titolo[20];
    char domanda[40];
    char risposte[3][50];
    int difficolta;
    struct Esercizio *nextEsercizio;
};
typedef struct Esercizio esercizio;
typedef esercizio *esercizioPtr;
```

```
void inserisciEsercizio(esercizioPtr *firstEsercizio, autorePtr Autore)
{
    listaEserciziPtr newLista = (listaEserciziPtr)malloc(sizeof (listaEsercizi));
    esercizioPtr newEsercizio = (esercizioPtr)malloc(sizeof (esercizio)); // <--- here! 

    //se ne stabiliscono i parametri
    if (newEsercizio != NULL)
    {
        newEsercizio->nextEsercizio = NULL;

        printf("Inserisci titolo esercizio ");
        scanf_s("%s", newEsercizio->titolo, 20);
        printf("Inserisci domanda esercizio: ");
        scanf_s("%s", newEsercizio->domanda, 30);
        printf("Inserisci difficolta esercizio: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &(newEsercizio->difficolta));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf(" Scrivere la risposta:\n");
            scanf_s("%s", newEsercizio->risposte[i], 100);
        }

        if (*firstEsercizio == NULL) //caso in cui creo il primo oggetto
        {
            *firstEsercizio = newEsercizio;
        }
        else //se non  il primo lo inserisco all'interno della lista oggetti
        {
            newEsercizio->nextEsercizio = *firstEsercizio;
            *firstEsercizio = newEsercizio;
        }

        //mettere malloc

        if (newLista != NULL)
        {
            newLista->nextListaEsercizi = NULL;
            newLista->esercizio = newEsercizio;

            if (Autore->esercizi == NULL) //caso in cui creo il primo oggetto
            {
                Autore->esercizi = newLista;

            }
            else //se non  il primo lo inserisco all'interno della lista oggetti
            {

                newLista->nextListaEsercizi = Autore->esercizi;
                Autore->esercizi = newLista;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //nel caso malloc restituisca NULL
            printf("Memoria non disponibile \n");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //nel caso malloc restituisca NULL
        printf("Memoria non disponibile \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The variables are written in Italian (half in Italian, half in English to be honest). Hope it's not too much of a problem."* - Well, you could just have translated everything. It often makes it way easier.

Comment: I mean. I suppose you have a reason for naming a variable `titolo` instead of `a`. But to me they make equal sense. Also, I suppose you would find `a` easier than `abzzzbiooj` or any long random sequence of letters. Same with your comments. To me they are just noise right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you declarations you have:

```
char risposte[3][50];
```

And later in the code you have:

```
scanf_s("%s", newEsercizio->risposte[i], 100);
```

It allows a 100 chars in a 50 chars array, which probaly leads to memory corruption in the first call to `inserisciEsercizio`. Using `sizeof` instead of a constant with `scanf_s` is usually a good idea:

```
scanf_s("%s", newEsercizio->risposte[i], sizeof(newEsercizio->risposte[i]));
```